# Dynamic query fields in Sor / Macro substitution in solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr

We've got a multilingual search index with the "field-per-language" configuration with a lot of similar aliases in the search handler like this:

```
<str name="f.content_en.qf">Title_en^10 Text_en^1 ...</str>
<str name="f.content_de.qf">Title_de^10 Text_de^1 ...</str>
...
```

They are used in the `q` parameter:

```
<str name="q">{!edismax qf=$searchField pf=$searchField v=$searchText}</str>
```

The client knows, which language should be used and calls Solr like this, e.g.: `/solr/core/search?searchText=TEXT&searchField=content_en`

That works fine, but the configuration contains a lot of similar stuff.
I'd like to optimize the config to something like this:

```
<str name="df">content</str>
<str name="f.content.qf">Title_${lang}^10 Text_${lang}^1...</str>
```

Then the client would need to provide the `lang` parameter only.

I tried to use `concat` function like this:

```
paramLang=en
searchFields=concat("Title", "_", "${paramLang}", " ", "Text", "_", "${paramLang}")
```

and use it as the `qf`:

```
q={!edismax qf=$searchFields v=$searchText}
```

But it seems, the local params `qf` does not support Solr functions.

Is is possible with Solr at all?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the [Parameter substitution / Macro Expansion](https://yonik.com/solr-query-parameter-substitution/) works fine.
The issue was with those macros in the `solrconfig.xml`: there is a conflict with Solr system properties substitution. Solr could not resolve the query parameter macros.

I could not find a proper way, how to escape query parameters (macros) and used the following workaround:

```
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        
        <str name="searchFields">
                    Title_${lang:${lang}}^10
                    Text_${lang:${lang}}^1
                    ...

    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="q">*</str>
        <str name="qf">${searchFields:${searchFields}}</str>
        <str name="pf">${searchFields:${searchFields}}</str>
        
        <str name="lang">en</str>
        ...
```

Query URL: `/search?q=TEXT&lang=en`

**Update**: proper way to deal with var substitution in `solrconfig.xml` - escape the dollar char by `$$`:

```
        <str name="searchFields">
                    Title_$${lang}^10
                    Text_$${lang}^1
                    ...
```

**Update #2**: do NOT define macros in the `invariant` or `append` sections when using a Solr Cloud! Otherwise, you'll a weird exception, e.g.:

```
"undefined field: \"Text_$\"
```

or

```
"msg": "Error from server at null: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Query Field '${searchFields}' is not a valid field name"
```

P.S. `wt=json` as "invariant" is also NOT compatible with Solr Cloud, giving "unexpected" content-type error.
So many "surprises" :(